# How to convert the paragraph into root words

Tags: c#, string, text, split, words

excuse me, i'm trying to make simple application which converting the words into word. for example

Enable = able
Payment = Pay

the text on my notepad was "enable payment"

i'm using 2 sample words above, and i'm not getting what i need. i wrote "enable" and "payment" on notepad.txt. then the application will start and get the word.

and the application will start trimming the words *cut the "En" and "ment"* so their result will be "able" and "pay"

my application can trim the single word "enable" to "able" . and "payment" to "pay" but, the application didn't work well if i write 2 words or more such as "enable payment" or "payment enable"

here is the user interface [image](http://i1085.photobucket.com/albums/j423/Nencor_Theleftbehind/1.jpg)

and here is the source code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace KTM'
{
public partial class KTM : Form
{
    public string notepad;
    public KTM()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Enabled=false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = false;
    }

    void enable()
    {
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string dir = Application.StartupPath.ToString();
        OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        fdlg.Title = "Open *txt files";
        fdlg.InitialDirectory = @dir;
        fdlg.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
        fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = fdlg.FileName;
        }
        else
        {

        }


      }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Equals(""))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            enable();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        notepad = textBox1.Text;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(notepad);
        string paragraf = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        string[] kata = paragraf.Split(' ');
        int i = 0;

        //MessageBox.Show(kata[0]+" "+kata[1]+" "+kata[2]);
        foreach (string ambil in kata)
        {
            if (kata[i].StartsWith("en"))
            {
                kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(2);
            }
            if(kata[i].EndsWith("ment"))
            {
                int len = kata[i].Length;
                int kepake = len - 4;
                kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(0, kepake);
            }


        }
        i++;
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(notepad);
        i = 0;
        foreach (string ambil in kata)
        {
            sw.Write(kata[i]+" ");
        }
        i++;
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();




        MessageBox.Show("Converted and Saved  ","KTM Stemming",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        notepad = textBox1.Text;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(notepad);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Stemming is not an easy process. I would recommend to use some libraries like Snowball analyzer in Lucene.Net http://www.apache.org/dist/incubator/lucene.net/source/2.9.4g-incubating/

Comment: Especially with English (and likely any language)  What happens when you come to the words "enter" or "lament"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    foreach (string ambil in kata)
    {
        if (kata[i].StartsWith("en"))
        {
            kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(2);
        }
        if(kata[i].EndsWith("ment"))
        {
            int len = kata[i].Length;
            int kepake = len - 4;
            kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(0, kepake);
        }


    }
```

this is part of your problem as it is a foreach but you are using it like a for loop. you probably want `for (int i=0; i<kata.Length; i++)` also you are writting to a file outside of your for loop, so either you need to put your writing in that for loop, or make another for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're foreach loops aren't designed properly.  Since you are updating the array inside the loop, you'd be better off doing a simple for loop with an iterator:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < kata.Length; i++)
    {
        if (kata[i].StartsWith("en"))
        {
            kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(2);
        }
        if(kata[i].EndsWith("ment"))
        {
            int len = kata[i].Length;
            int kepake = len - 4;
            kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(0, kepake);
        }
    }
```

But, in the second loop the foreach makes sense.  You need to use the ambil variable, though:

```
    foreach (string ambil in kata)
    {
        sw.Write(ambil + " ");
    }
```

EDIT:

You said the above does not work, but it does for me.  Perhaps your problem is related to some of the other code in your form.  Since it's not good practice to mix different kinds of logic in the same method, I would suggest breaking the root word parsing logic into its own method such as:

```
    private string getRootWords(string paragraf)
    {
        string[] kata = paragraf.Split(' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < kata.Length; i++)
        {
            if (kata[i].StartsWith("en"))
            {
                kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(2);
            }
            if (kata[i].EndsWith("ment"))
            {
                int len = kata[i].Length;
                int kepake = len - 4;
                kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(0, kepake);
            }
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string ambil in kata)
        {
            builder.Append(ambil + " ");
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

That method works for me.  When I call `getRootWords("Enable payment")`, it returns `able pay', which is the output that you wanted, as I understand it.

Comment: its not working, i dont have any idea where it goes wrong, the very first time i made the application, i was using iteration shown above, its not worked, then i try the foreach, then another confusing logic shown :(

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing the index variable `i` outside the loop, you should increment it inside:

```
    foreach (string ambil in kata) 
    { 
        if (kata[i].StartsWith("en")) 
        { 
            kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(2); 
        } 
        if(kata[i].EndsWith("ment")) 
        { 
            int len = kata[i].Length; 
            int kepake = len - 4; 
            kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(0, kepake); 
        } 
        i++; 
    }
```

better still use directly a `for` loop (you are not using the `ambil` variable):

```
    for (i=0; i<kata.Lenght; i++) 
    { 
        if (kata[i].StartsWith("en")) 
        { 
            kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(2); 
        } 
        if(kata[i].EndsWith("ment")) 
        { 
            int len = kata[i].Length; 
            int kepake = len - 4; 
            kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(0, kepake); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help guys ! :) i really really appreciate it, though i dont understand some answers :D at least you guys help me to construct the logic, and i solve my problem like this

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        notepad = textBox1.Text;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(notepad);
        string paragraf = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(notepad);
        string[] kata = paragraf.Split(' ');

        for (int i = 0; i < kata.Length; i++)
        {
            if (kata[i].StartsWith("en"))
            {
                kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(2);
                //cutting the EN*
            }

            if (kata[i].EndsWith("ment"))
            {
                int panjang = kata[i].Length;
                int sisa = panjang - 4;
                kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(0, sisa);
                //cutting the *Ment
            }

            if(kata[i].EndsWith("ous"))
            {
                int panjang = kata[i].Length;
                int sisa = panjang - 3;
                kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(0, sisa);
                //cutting the ous, tremendous, hazardous
            }

            if (kata[i].EndsWith("ied"))
            {
                int panjang = kata[i].Length;
                int sisa = panjang -1;
                kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(0, sisa);
                //cutting ied
            }

            if (kata[i].EndsWith("ly"))
            {
                int panjang = kata[i].Length;
                int sisa = panjang - 2;
                kata[i] = kata[i].Substring(0, sisa);
                //cutting fluently, diligently
            }
            sw.Write(kata[i] + " ");
        }

        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Converted and Saved  ", "KTM Stemming", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```